# Overriding notification Sound Android

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I'm trying to override a notification sound and play my own notification sound.
The current code is:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_24dp)
    .setContentTitle(text)
    .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
    .setSound(soundUri);
// Sets an ID for the notification
int mNotificationId = 2580;

// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

but the original notification  overriding (by sound) my sound.
is there any way of doing so?

**Edit:**

when i'm trying to play the sound both of the sound are playing. sometimes the original sound is first and something the custom sound is played first.

I want to hear only the custom sound.

Comment: How did you defined the soundUri? If default sound is being played, it may indicate that setSound(soundUri) is not setting the sound properly (wrong path for example)

Answer (score 0):

Create `res/raw` folder and put your notification sound into this folder

Try this

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysound);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should keep in mind when providing a custom notification sound.

- **Sound Uri**
  Your `soundUri` must be something like this:

  `Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +  context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.yourSound);`
- **Notification Defaults**
  Make sure you haven't used `.setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_ALL);`
  Many developers have observed that using `.setDefaults()` without `DEFAULT_SOUND` somehow overrides your custom sound. So remove `.setDefaults()` completely.
- **Sound file length**
  I've heard reports of no sound playing because the sound file is too long. Try limiting it to 5 seconds.

According to the code you've posted, the only possible error could be due to an invalid `soundUri`, so give that a look.